# How to input data from user into 2d array and cout to user c++

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

So I am fairly new to 2d arrays in c++ and I know im doing something wrong but im not sure what.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
  string favBands[10][2];

  cout << "Welcome to the favorite band printer outer!" << endl;

  int count = 1;
  string band;
  string song;
  for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    for(int j = 1; j < 2; j++){
      cout << "Enter your number " << count << " band:\n" << endl;
      count += 1;
      cin >> band;
      favBands[i][j] = band;
      cout << "Enter " << favBands[i][j] << "'s best song:\n" << endl;
      cin >> song;
      favBands[i][j] = song;
    }
  }
}
```

I want to ask the user to enter their 10 favorite bands and then ask for their favorite song from that band in a pair. So for example:

```
Enter your number 1 favorite band:

Black Eyed Peas (user input)

Enter your favorite Black Eyed Peas song:

Boom Boom Pow (user input)
```

I am able to do all of this but the problem comes when I try to print the array to the user. I think my problem may lie in how i input the user data into my array but im not sure how to fix it. Thanks!

Comment: `favBands[i][j] = band;` and `favBands[i][j] = song;` both write to the same spot. The rest you should be able to figure out yourself if you step through the program with a debugger or on a piece of paper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will only need one for loop. see we are storing data for 10 users. and for every user we are taking two data at `index 0` and `index 1`. So we don't need second for loop. please observe code and ask if you still have any confusion. I will be happy to figure it out as well.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

 int main(){
string favBands[10][2];

cout << "Welcome to the favorite band printer outer!" << endl;

int count = 1;
string band;
string song;
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
  cout << "Enter your number " << count << " band:\n" << endl;
  count += 1;
  cin >> band;
  favBands[i][0] = band;



  cout << "Enter " << favBands[i][0] << "'s best song:\n" << endl;
  cin >> song;
  favBands[i][1] = song;

  } 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Allow me to suggest using two separate arrays instead of a 2D array, one for bands and one for songs, and then cout'ing the song, like so:

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    int main() {
        string favBands[10];
        string favSongs[10];

        cout << "Welcome to the favorite band printer outer!" << endl;

        int count = 1;
        string band;
        string song;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            cout << "Enter your number " << count << " band:\n" << endl;
            count += 1;
            cin >> band;
            favBands[i] = band;
            cout << "Enter " << favBands[i] << "'s best song:\n" << endl;
            cin >> song;
            favSongs[i] = song;
            cout << "Your favorite song by " << favBands[i] << " is " << favSongs[i] << ".\n";
        }
    }
```

Although both bands and songs are strings, 2D arrays aren't really best suited for this type of problem.

Comment: Should work. Consider using a using one array of a structure that aggregates bands and songs. Almost always makes the book keeping easier to manage when searching and sorting enters the assignment.

Comment: It would be a lot easier to do it this way but I am trying to practice with 2d arrays, but thank you for the suggestion!